# How to sum total bookings for a particular flight

Tags: mysql, count, sum

Ok so i have two columns in a table. One of these says how many people the customer booked to go to a particular country.
The other column shows which country the order was booked for, for example, fiji, australia.
Im having trouble adding up the No_Of_People column in order to determine which flight destination has the most people going to it.
If there was only one booking per country this would be easy, as it would be something like:

```
select destination_name from bookings order by sum(No_Of_People) desc limit 1;
```

Just wondering how i can do this, knowing that there are multiple people booking for the same country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by destination to get the people per destination:

```
SELECT
  destination_name,
  sum(No_Of_People) AS count
FROM
  bookings
GROUP BY destination_name
ORDER BY count desc;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Josh if think this helpful, please upvote and/or accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(No_Of_People), destination_name from bookings group by destination_name order by sum(No_Of_People) desc
```

Comment: Thanks, incredibly helpful.

Comment: @Josh if think this helpful, please upvote and/or accept the answer